# Предложите два варианта функции, удаляющей из строки ведущие и концевые пробелы

Tags: c++

Задание: Предложите два варианта функции, удаляющей из строки ведущие и концевые пробелы
Помогите, пожалуйста,починить код программы:
Не выводит преобразованную строку, подскажите, что не так?

```
void FirstRemoveSpaces(char str[]) {
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(str); // определяем количество символов 
    for (i = 0, j = 0; str[i]; ++i)
        if (str[0] != ' ' || str[len - 1] != ' ') { // если не нашли пробел
            str[j++] = str[i]; // записываем в строку символ
        }
    str[j] = 0;
    cout << "Строка преобразована первым способом: ";
    puts(str); // вывод строки
}
```

И при во второй функции ошибки, не могу понять что не так?
    void SecondRemoveSpaces(string s) {

```
        if (s[0] == ' ')   
        {
            s.erase(0, 1); // удаление символа

        }

        int len = s.length - 1;
        if (s[len] == ' ')   
        {
            s.erase(len, 1); // удаление символа
        }

    }
```

Ну и полная программа:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void FirstRemoveSpaces(char str[]) {
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(str); // определяем количество символов 
    for (i = 0, j = 0; str[i]; ++i)
        if (str[0] != ' ' || str[len - 1] != ' ') { // если не нашли пробел
            str[j++] = str[i]; // записываем в строку символ
        }
    str[j] = 0;
    cout << "Строка преобразована первым способом: ";
    puts(str); // вывод строки
}



void SecondRemoveSpaces(string s) {

        if (s[0] == ' ')   // если встречается больше двух пробелов подряд
        {
            s.erase(0, 1); // удаление символа

        }

        int len = s.length - 1;
        if (s[len] == ' ')   // если встречается больше двух пробелов подряд
        {
            s.erase(len, 1); // удаление символа
        }

    }


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); // подключение русского языка
    char str[] = " Hi, this is a test! "; // инциализация строки
    string s = str;
    cout << "Строка: " << str << endl; // вывод строки
    FirstRemoveSpaces(str); // вызов первой функции
    SecondRemoveSpaces(s);
}
```

Comment: 1. `SecondRemoveSpaces(string &s)` забыли амперсанд. 2. `int len = s.length() - 1;` length() - функция.

Comment: Ну а если пробелов много?...

Answer (score 3):

Начнем со второй функции. Во первых, так как вы написали:

```
void SecondRemoveSpaces(string s)...
```

Это уже означает, что ваши все действия происходить будут с копией строкового обьекта, а не с самим обьектом. Поэтому ваш обьект по любому не изменит свое значение.  Правильно передавать ссыльку на обьект... Во вторых вы не учли, что пробелов может быть больше одного. Есть много способов. Я преставлю один:

```
void SecondRemoveSpaces(string& s)
{
    size_t first = s.find_first_not_of(' '),
            last = s.find_last_not_of(' ');
    s = (first != string::npos) ? s.substr(first, last - first + 1) : "";
}
```

Но удобнее, если такого рода функции  возвращают результат. Поэтому все таки лучше вариант:

```
string& SecondRemoveSpaces(string& s)
{
    size_t first = s.find_first_not_of(' '),
            last = s.find_last_not_of(' ');
    s = (first != string::npos) ? s.substr(first, last - first + 1 ) : "";
    return s;
}
```

Чтобы в программе мы могли бы сразу выполнить присвоение или, например выводить:

```
cout << SecondRemoveSpaces(s);
```

С первой функцией дела по другому обстоят. Учитывая, что массивы передаются по ссыльке, то по синтаксису все верно, но в логике функции есть ошибки, которые лучше обьяснять правильным кодом, дабы не быть слышком многословным...

```
void FirstRemoveSpaces(char str[]) {
    size_t  i = 0,  len = strlen(str); //  количество символов
    while(str[--len] == ' ');
    while (str[i++] == ' ');
    if (i == 1) //не было пробелов
        str[++len] = '\0';
    else {
        --i; // это количество начальных пробелов
        size_t j = 0;
        while (j <= len - i)  {
            str[j] = str[j + i]; // сдвигаем все влево на i
            ++j;
        }
        str[j] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Другой вариант без проверки условий:

```
string& RemoveSpaces(string& s) {    
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(' '));
    auto f = [](char c) { return c != ' '; };
    s.erase((std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), f)).base(), s.end());
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Ну а с первой функцией у вас вообше  серьезные логические ошибки

Comment: C `substr` немного не так будет, у нее второй параметр - длина. Что-то вроде `s = (first != last ? s.substr(first, last-first+1) : "");`. (Проверка на равенство улаживает ситуацию, когда в строке одни пробелы.)

Comment: Судя по всему, как раз-таки с первого аргумента. *"Можно просто тестировать..."* [А я протестировал.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f476fef419d3a068) Вариант `s = s.substr(first, last);` выдает неправильный результат (не обрезает часть пробелов в конце строки). Если в строке нет ничего, кроме пробелов, этот вариант у меня вообще крашится. А `s = (first != last ? s.substr(first, last-first+1) : "");` работает нормально в обоих случаях.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  да, вы правы, я просто забыл добавить проверку. Конечно в таком случаи  firs == string::npos.... Спасибо

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну а по поводу  второго аргумента  substr,  не соглашусь

Comment: Так вроде по тестам видно, что `last - first + 1` работает, а `last` - нет?

Comment: Значит у нас с вами разные реализации string?.. ))) Непонятно, почему у вас так

Comment: Запустите у себя `std::cout << std::string("abcdef").substr(2,3)`. Какой вывод?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я еще раз прочитал про метод, вы правы.  Я  помнил и тестировал неверно... Запутался здорово конечно: старость не радость..

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan а можете написать код без использования ?, использовав if?

Comment: без проблем, можно написать десятки разных функций

Comment: Я добавил в ответ, но не было учтено случай, когда в строке все пробелы. Теперь исправил

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan а у тебя вижуал не ругался на find_if? У меня ошибка вылезает:  namespace std члена find if

Comment: наверное вы не подключили файл <algorithm>

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Да, вы были правы)
И еще хотел спросить,  вот функция с проверкой условия, чуть-чуть не понял. Сначала мы ищем позиции первого и последнего, затем проверяем если позиция первого найдена, то удаляем пробелы, но зачем  :""; ?

Comment: Условие означает, если все же не был найден не пробел, т.е. в строке все пробелы( хотя так не бывает, но мало ли...), то инициализировать строку пустой строкой.